# Packages dependency and includes

Tags: ros, catkin, build, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a **package1** which generates services via a Type1.srv file. These generated services are located in **<catkin_ws>/devel/include/package1/Type1.h**. This all works fine.

Now when I want a **package2** to also use the services generated in **package1** I follow the steps described [in here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html).

Note that in my code I do not actually add *package1* to *find_package*, because *package1* is not compiled yet when *find_package* is called in *package2*.

Now when building I get the following error:

```
<catkin_ws>/src/package2/src/MyFile.cpp:2:32: fatal error: package1/Type1.h: No such file or directory
```

When I manually add include path **<catkin_ws>/devel/include** to **include_directories**, it compiles and links fine, but it is obviously very dirty...

Anyone knows what I am missing here? How can I let my system know about the include path to **devel**?

**-------------------EDIT 1---------------**

Note that when I add **package1** to **find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ... package1)** I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "package1" with any of the following names:

    package1Config.cmake
    package1-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "package1" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "package1_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "package1" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

**-------------------EDIT 2---------------**

File **package1/package.xml** does exist and has the following name

```
<package format="2">
  <name>package1</name>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
```

**package1/CMakeLists.txt** contains

```
project(package1)

...

catkin_package(
    LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
    CATKIN_DEPENDS rtt_ros message_runtime std_msgs
)
```

and **package2/CMakeLists.txt** contains

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs package1)
```

This causes the error described above.

**-------------------EDIT 3---------------**

I have created a MWE which can be found [in this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4i1g-UqIF8yTWUtNmhpYkRZQlE). Both packages are in meta-package **le_painters_companion**, **package1** corresponds to **lc_control** and **package2** to **lc_toolkitLink**.

Does this MWE shed some more light on the problem?

Kind regards,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243672/packages-dependency-and-includes/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2016-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Note that in my code I do not actually add *package1* to *find_package*, because *package1* is not compiled yet when *find_package* is called in *package2*.

> Now when building I get the following error:

> ```
> <catkin_ws>/src/package2/src/MyFile.cpp:2:32: fatal error: package1/Type1.h: No such file or directory
> ```

> I thought that the path to **<catkin_ws>/devel/include/package1/Type1.h** would be provided as an include by the dependency set in package2's package.xml file, no?

Indeed: no.

I thought this was actually explained in one of your earlier questions ([CMakeLists.txt vs package.xml](http://answers.ros.org/question/217475)), but just to reiterate: `package.xml` (where you put the `build_depend`) and `CMakeLists.txt` (`find_package(..)` and friends) are two separate things.

The former is used by (meta-)package managers (such as `rosdep`, but ultimately `apt`, `dfn` and others) to understand how your package relates to all others (in terms of dependencies, ie: which pkgs should be on the system, separated out into two sets: 'when running' and 'when compiling'), while the latter is a *codification of the actual process* to follow when converting your sources into binary artefacts (ie: compiling into objects and executable binaries).

In other words: how would the compiler know about `package1` if you don't add it to `package2`'s `INCLUDE_PATH` etc? That is `CMakeLists.txt`'s task (via `find_package(..)`), and you deliberately left that out of there.

Compilation order is (partially) determined by the contents of the `find_package(..)` calls, so:

> Note that in my code I do not actually add `package1` to `find_package`, because `package1` is not compiled yet when `find_package` is called in `package2`.

is a bit of strange statement, as I hope you understand now.

---

Edit:

> I thought that the path to **<catkin_ws>/devel/include/package1/Type1.h** would be provided as an include by the dependency set in **catkin_package**, via the **CATKIN_DEPENDS** keyword, no?

Not if you don't `find_package(catkin COMPONENTS .. package1 ..)` in `package2`'s `CMakeLists.txt`.

> Though when I do use **catkin_package / CATKIN_DEPENDS** to indicate the dependency on **package1**, I have no more luck.

No, because listing `package1` under `CATKIN_DEPENDS` only causes the `catkin_package(..)` call to configure the build system to generate a `PkgConfig` (`.pc`) file for `package2` that states the dependency on `package1`. It does not update the compilation process with any new information regarding the location of `package1`.

(well, actually it will try to, as the `PkgConfig` file will need the same set of information, but since you don't `find_package(.. package1 ..)` anywhere, the variables need will most likely be empty).

`CMakeLists.txt` in `package2` does not explicitly import `package1`, so even if `package1` exports something, `package2` won't know about it.

> Additionally, I would expect **${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}** to include the path to **<catkin_ws>/devel/include/package1/Type1.h**, but **${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}** only contains the path to ros core installation.

Which makes sense, as you don't `find_package(catkin COMPONENTS .. package1 ..)` in `package2`'s `CMakeLists.txt`.

Without an explicit `find_package(.. package1 ..)` somewhere in the `CMakeLists.txt` of `package2`, nothing you do in `package1` will be picked up by any of the build activities undertaken by the build tool that builds `package2`.

---

Edit2:

> Note that when I add **package1** to **find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ... package1)** I get the following error:

> ```
> CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "package1" with any of the following names:
> ```

> ```
>     package1Config.cmake
> ```

```
    package1-config.cmake
```

> ```
>   Add the installation prefix of "package1" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "package1_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "package1" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
> ```

(after all the edits, it's no longer visible, but I feel as if the original question was a good example of an xy-problem)

The first thing to check is that a file `package1/package.xml` actually exists. If that is the case, check the package name. Make sure it corresponds to the one you add to `find_package(..)` (in `package2`) and to `catkin_package()` (in `package1`).

---

Edit3:

> I have created a MWE which can be found [in this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4i1g-UqIF8yTWUtNmhpYkRZQlE). Both packages are in meta-package **le_painters_companion**, **package1** corresponds to **lc_control** and **package2** to **lc_toolkitLink**.

<del>If I understand you correctly, you have both `package1` and `package2` in the directory of the `lc_control` metapackage? I'm not sure that is supposed to work. Could you please try flattening your workspace? So make `package1` and `package2` siblings of your metapackage.</del>

No, this is not correct. I was confused by you using the name *meta-package* for a directory containing other packages. I typically reserve that name for actual [metapackage](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#metapackage)s.

> Does this MWE shed some more light on the problem?

No, not really. It wasn't an actual MWE, as it is still full of project-specific CMake statements and paths.

It's hard for me to test, but by commenting out all the `orocos_component(..)` calls (and related lines), I can get a sample workspace containing your two packages to build just fine. *With* `lc_control` listed in both `find_package(catkin .. COMPONENTS .. lc_control)` and in `catkin_package(.. CATKIN_DEPENDS .. lc_control)`.

The `CMakeLists.txt` of both packages are actually quite convoluted. Perhaps it would help if you stripped them completely (comment almost everything), have just the bare Catkin skeleton in there, then try to build your workspace. See if `lc_toolkitLink` can find `lc_control`. Then start re-enabling the orocos and other bits. I suspect that at some point things will break.

Additionally: I assume you've already removed your `build` and `devel` directories and rebuild everything from scratch?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-09-13**:
You are right, my comment on package.xml is useless. I have updated the post accordingly and added an update to provide more details on why I did not add package1 to find_package. Although my problem is not solved yet, it looks like you are pointing towards the right direction.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-09-13**:
I believe you are right about the xy problem (I have tried to narrow things down now, so the post is useful for later use to others). I have added a 2nd edit to give some more information.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-13**:
Something is not right here. If you can, try and create an MWE, or provide access to both packages somehow. We don't need the sources (they can be empty), but it would help to see the complete `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` of both packages, and the directory layout as well.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-09-14**:
Hello gvdhoorn, I believe your edit3 is wrong: **package1** and **package2** are actually dummy names used to make the post as generic as possible. Their real name (in the MWE) are **lc_control** (for **package1** and **lc_toolkitLink** (for **package2**).

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-09-14**:
... and it turns out that  **lc_control** and **lc_toolkitLink** are already both in a metapackage (called **le_painters_companion**).

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-09-19**:
Hello gvdhoorn, using the stripe down technique you suggested and hours of analysis I have been able to solve the problem described in my post. There are still problems to my build though whiich are very closely linked, but I believe they deserve another post. Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-09-19**:
Note that the problem arouse because, in **package1**, the name of the produced library was not the name of the project **package1**, hence I was not allowed to use **LIBRARY ${PROJECT_NAME}** in **catkin_package()**.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-19**:\

> [..] and hours of analysis [..]

I'm sorry to hear that.

> I have been able to solve the problem described in my post

Glad to hear that you got to the bottom of it though.